# How to add tooltip for indicators plot using dojocharts

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting

I am creating a bar chart using dojocharts and version is 1.9 .Here i add a Indicator to a bar chart. I want the add text with html tag(like break tag) and also tooltip on the Indicator. I have added a labelFunc to return the HTML I want, but it only shows  as plain text. here html tag and tooltip for that indicators not working.Any one suggest me is it possible for add tooltip and html tag on indicator of dojocharts.

Below is my code

```
    Chart.addPlot("indicator", { type: "Indicator", 
      vertical:false,
      values:30,
       offset: { y: -2, x: -50 },
       lineStroke: { color: "green",style: "line" },
       labels: true,
      htmlLabels: true,   
      // start:true,
      // labelStyle:"inside",
            //maxBarSize: 35,

        fontColor:"red",  
       // precision: 1,
        labelFunc: max,
        stroke: {color:"rgb(204, 204, 204)",height:40,width: 25},
        outline: "purple",
        fill: "#666"
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Tooltip plugin.

For an example see this tutorial https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/charting/
The plugin is called dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip and it is described here https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.7/dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip

Comment: Thank you for your response.here i am trying this tooltip but not working. Here is my code.         var t2=  new Tooltip(chart, "indicator", {
            text: function(chartItem) {
                console.debug(chartItem);
               return "hello";
                
            }
        });    So tell me how can i show tooltip for indicator